# Was this character from Star Trek Beyond on Archer's ship?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, star-trek-beyond

Be forewarned that there are major spoilers ahead.

In *Star Trek Beyond*, we find out that

> the villain Krall is actually a human: Captain Balthazar Edison of the USS Franklin, who served in Starfleet at the beginning of the Federation and was previously a MACO who fought in the Xindi and Romulan wars, earning respect as a hero.

As I recall, the only MACOs who actually saw action in the Xindi campaign were the ones assigned to Archer's ship.

This leads me to ask:

> **Did Krall serve aboard Archer's Enterprise?**

Answer (score 8):

He wasn't explicitly said to have been, but he theoretically could have. The fact that he mentions the Xindi incident as a conflict he fought in may imply he was on board. Since Enterprise was the only Earth ship in the Expanse, most other MACOs would have spent little to no time fighting Xindi.

As to the point about chronology, Starfleet would certain have kept older warp 4 ships around well after the NX class debut. The Enterprise episode First Flight (when humans first achieve warp 2) occurs only 8 years before the 2151 launch of Enterprise, so Franklin is less than a decade older than NX-01. Besides, they say in Beyond that Franklin was lost in the 2160s.

In any event, Franklin must have been lost after Enterprise ended and the Federation formed because it is a plot point that Edison became a captain in Starfleet because the MACOs were disbanded.

Answer (score 0):

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/MACO_personnel#Defense_force_MACO) quotes an unnamed black MACO. He can be, however his face is not so similar.

Answer (score -3):

No.  The *Franklin* is described in the movie as being "the first Warp 4 ship".  Archer's *Enterprise* was the first Warp 5 vessel.  That makes Archer's ship's adventures much later in the chronology than the Franklin.  If Edison was the captain of the Franklin, there's no way he could have been an underling on a later ship.

Comment: Not true. MACOs were not stationary to a given ship like the normal crew. MACOs move on an as needed basis using Starships as transportation or as asignments but not as a base of operation. There is a US military equivalent. I'm just not sure which one uses ships to get around, but are not in the same line of command as most of the rest of the navy.

Comment: I thought about this (the Warp 4 issue) and I figured that perhaps the warp scale had been readjusted between the Enterprise and TOS eras, just as it had been between the TOS and TNG eras, and so Scotty’s “Warp 4” might be Archer’s “Warp 7”.  After all, the Franklin was registered with NX followed by 3 digits, which would place it *after* Archer's Enterprise chronologically.

Comment: You make a ton of assumptions. You assume that Edison was the first captain of the _Franklin_, and you assume that Warp 4 ships were all suddenly retired as soon as _one_ Warp 5 ship entered service. I see 10-15 year old cars on the road all the time, and I doubt many of them are being driven by their first owners. There are problems with the Franklin (the registry isn't necessarily one - NX-01 obviously wasn't the first ship in Starfleet; what were the other ones registered as?) but chronology isn't one as far as I can see.

Comment: Actually it would make sense to give a captain-only-because-you-were-MACO (a strange notion in itself) an older, less powerful ship than someone who, y'know, actually made their way up to Captain.